# Asset thumb missing

Tags: assets, image

I have a problem where some image assets do not produce thumbs. It seems Craft has an issue generating the thumbnail of large images (in pixel-values, not filesize).

Does anyone know if this is a known bug, or if it has anything to do with the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're most likely running into some environmental limitation... PHP's [memory_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) being the most likely scenario.  Try bumping that in your php.ini file and see if that helps.

If it doesn't, check your `craft/storage/runtime/logs` files for any [error] or [warning] entries.